# Does Python have something like Perl 5.10's "state" variables?

Tags: python, perl

In Perl 5.10, I can say:

```
sub foo () {
  state $x = 1;
  say $x++;
}

foo();
foo();
foo();
```

...and it will print out:

```
1
2
3
```

Does Python have something like this?

Comment: To python fans: Note that state variables are not just used for generators in Perl.  They are a handy way of encapsulating information that needs to persist with some function throughout its lifetime. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest parallel is probably to attach values to the function itself.

```
def foo():
    foo.bar = foo.bar + 1

foo.bar = 0

foo()
foo()
foo()

print foo.bar # prints 3
```

Comment: +1 idiom for static variables in Python, although in practice you never need them.

Comment: Didn’t you just create a non-private variable!? Oh my!

Comment: I love how python fans generally refer to any language feature not directly included as 'not needed in practice.', regardless of feature.  :)

Comment: There is a lot in ANY language that is "not needed". But if it helps you write correct programs, it's a GOOD THING. Perl's state variables do that.

Answer (score 18):

A class may be a better fit here (and is usually a better fit for anything involving "state"):

```
class Stateful(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.state_var = 0

    def __call__(self):
        self.state_var = self.state_var + 1
        print self.state_var

foo = Stateful()
foo()
foo()
```

Comment: Just trying to be explicit in the example.

Comment: That’s pretty heavy-weight for such a simple thing, don’t you think?

Comment: tchrist: "heavy" is relative. Most use-cases would never notice the difference in weight.

Answer (score 9):

Python has generators which do something similar:

[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/can-somebody-explain-me-the-python-yield-statement)

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but python has generator functions that don't return a value per se, but a generator object that generates a new value everytime

```
def gen():
   x = 10
   while True:
      yield x
      x += 1
```

usage:

```
>>> a = gen()
>>> a.next()
10
>>> a.next()
11
>>> a.next()
12
>>> a.next()
13
>>>
```

look here for more explanation on [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/can-somebody-explain-me-the-python-yield-statement):
[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/can-somebody-explain-me-the-python-yield-statement)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to implement a closure in python:

```
def outer():
    a = [4]
    def inner():
        print a[0]
        a[0] = a[0] + 1
    return inner

fn = outer()
fn() # => 4
fn() # => 5
fn() # => 6
```

I borrowed this example verbatim from a [python mailing list post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-July/270951.html).

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'm recommending this, but just for fun:

```
def foo(var=[1]):
    print var[0]
    var[0] += 1
```

This works because of the [way mutable default arguments](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) work in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, though you have to declare your global variable first before it is encountered in `foo`:

```
x = 0

def foo():
    global x
    x += 1
    print x

foo()
foo()
foo()
```

EDIT: In response to the comment, it's true that python has no static variables scoped within a function. Note that `x` in this example is only exposed as global to the rest of the module. For example, say the code above is in `test.py`. Now suppose you write the following module:

```
from test import foo
x = 100
foo()
foo()
```

The output will be only `1` and `2`, not `101` and `102`.

Comment: Not the same, because the variable is not scoped inside the function -- it's exposed to the rest of the code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Python does not have static variables, so this is the only way to do it without going the class route. However, note that this is only exposed to the rest of the module as global.

Comment: state variables are lexical, not global (which is the main point of them, something LIKE a global that 'remembers' but without the downsides of being an actual global)

Comment: Isn’t this sort of lack of support for proper scoping one of Python’s Achilles’ heels? Will this be fixed in Python 3000?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use something like

```
def static_num2():
    k = 0
    while True:
        k += 1
        yield k

static = static_num2().next

for i in range(0,10) :
    print static()
```

to avoid a global var. Lifted from [this link](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread33025.html) about the same question.

Comment: Also, in a fairly recent python, you could do `static= itertools.count().next` and drop the `static_num2` definition.

Answer (score 2):

The preferable way is to use [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604622/does-python-have-something-like-perl-5-10s-state-variables/604645#604645) or [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604622/does-python-have-something-like-perl-5-10s-state-variables/604658#604658) (`yield`).

For the sake of completeness here's a variant w/ closure in Python 3.x:

```
>>> def make_foo():
...     x = 1
...     def foo():
...         nonlocal x
...         print(x)
...         x += 1
...     return foo
...
>>> foo = make_foo()
>>> foo()
1
>>> foo()
2
>>> foo()
3
```

Comment: For all Python ≥2.5: import itertools; foo = itertools.count(1).next

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: Wrong. NOTE: there is a `print`. Anyway the purpose is to demonstrate how to bind nonlocal name.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def foo():
    x = 1
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1


>>> z = iter(foo())
>>> next(z)
1
>>> next(z)
2
>>> next(z)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another dirty cheap way to do it, it's a variation on Tryiptich's answer, but using decorators

```
def static_var( name, value ):
    def dec( function ):
        setattr( function, name, value )
        return function
    return dec


@static_var( 'counter', 0 )
def counting_function():
    counting_function.counter = counting_function.counter + 1
    print counting_function.counter



"""
>>> counting_function()
1
>>> counting_function()
2
>>> counting_function()
3
>>> counting_function()
4
>>> counting_function()
5
>>> 
"""
```